# Windows 7 - BSOD PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED even after System Restore

Tags: windows-7, windows, hard-drive

OK, so I have a custom-built Win7 64-bit computer. Recently, on start-up. I get the `PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` BSOD. Then my computer does a system restore and I lose a bit of coding files then I'm all good.

The problem is... even after I do a `System Restore`, I turn it off and then turn it back on the next morning... I STILL get `PROCESS1_INITIALIZATION_FAILED` and I have to keep doing what I did the day before.

How do I fix this... please? I can't even boot into safe mode, either with this...

Comment: I would do sfc /scannow but more information about the drivers loaded is required

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug check indicates that the initialization of the Microsoft Windows operating system failed.
To work around this issue, start the computer from the disc drive or from the USB drive by using the Windows installation media. Delete the `Bootcat.cache` file, and then restart the computer.

**Note** The Bootcat.cache file is located at `%SystemRoot%\system32\codeintegrity`

Hope this help and please let us know if it helps.

Comment: Can't I just skip the hassle of making a windows installation media and do system restore. Once I am back ine like normal.. go back there and delete it?

Comment: @weka: I know how disgusting it is, but almost the most recommended way is this. Please check this too : http://support.microsoft.com/kb/981833.

Comment: Where would I download the win7 professional installation media recovery disk... :$

Comment: Don't you have the installation disk? You may find a list of solutions [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/6cc27c2e-ca5e-44ac-af65-8bf55f379f7e/where-can-i-find-windows-7-installation-media) so choose the one that suits you more.

Comment: Oh yes.. I have one. Now I am at the System Recovery Options... choose a recovery tools...where do I go from here...

Comment: OK so I did system rapair from what I gathered and in less than a minute it said my computer was repiared and it restarted... I am back in and its now installing all of my device driver software like USB and stuff...

edit: My computer rolled back many months... I see my old desktop and other applications.

Comment: I seem to have split up my computer into two hard disks........ what the

Comment: @weka I don't get the point, please explain more.

Comment: I system system repair. It finished. I went back in. Whjen I start up, I have Windows Boot manager with `Windows 7` and `Windows 7 (recovered)`. The Windows 7 is a version of my OS from Oct 2013. The Windows 7 recovered is still the same with the issue persistant... but now I can go into Windows 7 and probably deleted the boot cahce from Windows 7 recovered?

Comment: Let me know, after the repair can you boot the system using your old version of windows 7?

Comment: Yes I can. I can dual boot into the old one

Comment: Ok, so delete it and please report the result. Probably an update after the deletion will be useful.

Comment: Okay just deleted that boot cache file from HD of the OS I originally had a problem on... waiting to restart. It's installing update 1 of 34 <_< .. Oh lets say I DO get in... would I have to delete the OLD od my computer just put on because i DON'T want to dualboot...

Comment: First, please complete your sentences so as to I can interpret them :) Second, you were supposed to just boot using that repair disk, but I think you've completely installed a new copy! Third, did the problem solved on the old windows?

Comment: OK I just dual-booted into the Windows 7 recovered OS (the one giving me BSOD) and It says Confiuring Windows updates........ what? So there's no more BSOD but now it's configuring...

Comment: Ok, so I think the problem has solved. It will reconfigure your boot settings and as I said probably a windows update may be required depending on its service pack.

Comment: Ok thank you very much for your help. I mark this solved. Now I will try to delete the dualboot of the OS I do not need. :)

Comment: You're welcome. Happy to hear that. Good luck.

Comment: So something happened. I was out while waiting the Configuring Windows update screen was finished. I came back to the Systems Recovery tools. I cancel that. I go back and Dual-boot into Windows 7 recovery and now I'm back to Windows Conifugirng Windows Updates ... so we will see what happens... when I need help, a new thread will appear

Comment: @weka: Sorry all of these happened when I was slept :) Do you still have some problem?